# Django ImageField Image Not found

Tags: django-views, django-urls

doesn't work when I change it this way

```
path('<str:gameslug>/player/<str:slug>',player_detail,name="player_detail"), //don't work 404 not found error
```

before changing (was working)

```
  path('player/<str:slug>',player_detail,name="player_detail"), // was working
```

models.py

```
image=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to='player')
```

ERROR:Page not found (404)

Answer (score 0):

i changed `upload_to='player` to

> Now it is more clear

```
def create_path(instance, filename):
        import os.path
        return os.path.join(
             instance.game.slug,
             filename
        )
```

now URL; media/gameslug/filepath